# how to implement with clause in main query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query and for better performance I wrote a with clause. Now main issue is I don't know how to implement with clause in  main select query?  do i join with clause ? Can anyone please guide me here. Appreciated for any help.

```html
Begin
OPEN p_resultset FOR
with inputs  as (  
  select s.sid, t.number, s.state, t.city "city"
  from student s
  join dpartment t on t.dept_id = s.sid
  where s.act_status in ('A, 'B')
  and t.city in (select city from empCity g)
     )
     
     //how to implement above with clause in my below main query 
     
     select s.sid, s.state, get_name("name", e.fullname) "name", e.endDate
     
     from All_Emp e
     join student s on e.id = s.sid and s.act_status = 'A'
     join student ss on s.sid=ss.sid and ss.act_status = 'D'
     join department t on s.sid = t.dept_id
     join performance l on l.pid = s.sid
     join empcity g on s.city = g.city
     
     where 
     
     where e.endDate > s.endDate
```

Comment: A `WITH` clause is not for better performance, but for readability. It is unclear what you actually want to achieve with it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I am suffering from query performance. Every table I am using is indexed still performance is very slow. I was trying to preload data in WITH and use that in join clause in a hope that my query will avoid full table scan

Comment: As mentioned, a `WITH` clause is meant to enhance a query's readability. It doesn't make a query run faster. You can delete your request, as it makes no sense. The same seems to be true for your query by the way. A student's sid is not a student ID, but an employee ID? And at the same time it's a department ID and a performance ID? What the heck? This query is obviously incorrect, so why ask how to make it faster???

Answer (score 0):

You reference the CTE just as you would a table or view.  So somewhere in the `FROM` clause you would have:

```
from . . .
     input i
     . . .
```

You can then join it appropriately.

Comment: I am confused as you can see I am selecting similar data in with clause and in main select also join are similar on both so what do I replace and where do I put join with clause. Any example will be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

You can use like a some table name with your given alias "inputs" .

```sql
WITH inputs AS
(
       SELECT s.sid,
              t.number,
              s.state,
              t.city "city"
       FROM   student s
       join   dpartment t
       ON     t.dept_id = s.sid
       WHERE  s.act_status IN ('A',
                               'B')
       AND    t.city IN
              (
                     SELECT city
                     FROM   empcity g))
SELECT s.sid,
       s.state,
       Get_name("name", e.fullname) "name",
       e.enddate
FROM   all_emp e  
join   performance l
ON     l.pid = s.sid
join   empcity g
ON     s.city = g.city
join   inputs i
ON     i.sid=e.id --here is your "with select"
WHERE
where  e.enddate > s.enddate
```

Comment: yilmaz are you sure this is the right way cuz all code is same we are just adding CTE in join. I thought I have to remove some redundant join statement if use CTE

Comment: ah sorry, yes you are right.my inattention.You can remove , i ll also edit.